# telnetlib Read_Until With regexs

Tags: python, telnet

I want to read until for Multiple Prompts in the TelnetLib Library.

```
tn.read_until(b"login: ")
```

Thats what im currently using but as you can see it only waits for "login:" Prompt.

Now in perl the solution for me was:

```
$t->waitfor('/[:>%\$#]/');
```

Any way i can convert the code?

Answer (score 2):

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.expect:

> Telnet.expect(list[, timeout])
>
> Read until one from a list of a regular
>   expressions matches.
>
> The first argument is a list of regular expressions, either compiled
>   (regex objects) or uncompiled (strings). The optional second argument
>   is a timeout, in seconds; the default is to block indefinitely.
>
> Return a tuple of three items: the index in the list of the first
>   regular expression that matches; the match object returned; and the
>   text read up till and including the match.
>
> If end of file is found and no text was read, raise EOFError.
>   Otherwise, when nothing matches, return (-1, None, text) where text is
>   the text received so far (may be the empty string if a timeout
>   happened).
>
> If a regular expression ends with a greedy match (such as .*) or if
>   more than one expression can match the same input, the results are
>   non-deterministic, and may depend on the I/O timing.

Comment: Thanks for the Answerer but im not using Telnet.expect. im trying to keep it with tn.read_until...

Comment: According to the docs, `read_until` only takes string arguments. `expect` seems to do the same thing as `read_until` but accepts a list of regex objects, and is a little more verbose in the return value.